# Unit testing loading images/pages

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am writing unit tests for a web application using Python/Selenium and JS/jQuery. The test in question involves ensuring that a message with animated icon displays after the user submits a payment before the confirmation screen loads.

The payment is handled via a third-party iframe. The loading message and image do not display on a different URL -- it's the same URL as where the iframe itself is.

I've tried using JavaScript to stop the page load with `self.driver.execute_script("return window.stop;")`, but this isn't working.

I've also tried using Selenium to send the escape key with `self.driver.find_element_by_tag("body").send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)` but this is also failing to stop the page load before the confirmation page loads.

I've also tried just `assert "Loading Text" in self.driver.page_source` without stopping the loading of the confirmation screen, but this also didn't work.

If I manually click the stop button, it does stop the page load. I tried using this function to simulate a click on the stop button, but no avail. A stop button never appears during the automated test -- it remains a reload button even though the page is processing a request.

```
def stop_page_load():
    def click_based_on_coordinates(x,y):
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

        click_based_on_coordinates(78, 50)
```

Not at all sure how to test this item. Thoughts?

Comment: Would it be possible to post the html?

Comment: And as a clarification, are you looking to ensure that the animated message is displayed before the confirmation screen loads?